# different transition-delay for state changes

Tags: css, css-transitions

Trying to apply a transition on :hover with a different delay for the start and end of the event. CSS below changes the color over .25s after a .35s delay - I want to change the delay to 1.5s when the hover state ends... Any suggestions?

```
span {
    transition:.25s linear .35s;
    color:white
}

span:hover {
    color:black
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted - needed to break the transition out into a comma-separated list for each transitioned element, then specify a different delay value. Easy really, in hindsight.